# .net error - Server Error in '/' Application

Tags: c#, asp.net, exception

I am wondering if anyone possibly has a solution to the problem I am facing with an asp website I have been asked to work on.  However I do not have any experience with Microsoft .net framework.

**The problem is as follows:**

**The websites front page does not load, but instead throws the following error:**

> Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
>
> Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of
>   the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more
>   information about the error and where it originated in the code.
>
> Exception Details: System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not
>   set to an instance of an object.
>
> Source Error:
>
> An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the
>   current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of
>   the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.
>
> Stack Trace:
>
> [NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an
>   object.]    Incon.Default.Page_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e) +261
>   System.Web.Util.CalliHelper.EventArgFunctionCaller(IntPtr fp, Object
>   o, Object t, EventArgs e) +14
>   System.Web.Util.CalliEventHandlerDelegateProxy.Callback(Object sender,
>   EventArgs e) +35    System.Web.UI.Control.OnLoad(EventArgs e) +99
>   System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() +50
>   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean
>   includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)
>   +627

The rest of the pages does not have problem in loading at all and I am wasting a lot of time trying to figure out where the problem has come in.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Welcome at `Stackoverflow.com`...`Object reference not set to an instance of an object` states that something is null on your `Page_Load` event of `Default.aspx` page. Set a breakpoint on it and verify...you will solve your problem by yourself..Hope this helps

Comment: you can debug the page and find where is the null value you are using on the page load

Comment: Ali Baghdadi - how would I debug the page on the asp application?

Comment: @MayankPathak: Stack Overflow shouldn't be in a `code span`, that's meant for actual code. ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the code you have supplied (which is no code) it's very hard to pinpoint the exact cause of this. What can be said is that an object that you're trying to access is, for some reason, null.

The stacktrace indicates that it seems to be one of your usercontrols that you're probably trying to access around line 261 in the Page_Load method of code-behind file of the page.

Make sure your usercontrols have an ID and a runat="server" attribute and that you are able to access them from the code behind file.